# Why won't the SVG load in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, svg, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am injecting some HTML into websites using a chrome extension. In that code I am including an SVG. But when I load websites I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/SVG/home-outline.svg
```

All of my svg files are in a folder called SVG. I am loading the SVG files with `"web_accessible_resources": ["SVG/*.svg"]` as I have loaded my other files. Why won't my image load?

```
<span class="menu_T">
    <button class="large_menu_button_T">
        <img src="SVG/home-outline.svg">
    </button>
</span>
```

I get the same result when I try to add the svg through css background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the injected code, relative paths like `"SVG/home-outline.svg"` point to the site you're injecting to.

You need a full path to the resource in your extension. It's easy to get it: [`chrome.runtime.getURL("SVG/home-outline.svg")` does the job](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL).