# Chrome Extension Asset Blocked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I'm using SVG sprites in my extension and it works in Firefox, but Chrome is blocking the asset because it's cross-origin.

[image]

[image]

and it's listed as a web accessible resource

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "svgs/*.svg"
],
```

I'm not understanding why Chrome is blocking it.

To add, I'm using an SVG sprite in an `<svg>`/`<use>` element. It appears that Chrome blocks this, at least on sites with HTTPS: 

`Unsafe attempt to load URL chrome-extension://ainfdhapdnpfbjbnjojoediompjnmkom/svgs/fa-regular.svg#clock`

However, Firefox does not block using SVGs in this way. I tested using a non-SVG sprite file for the body background image as demonstrated in Savaratkar answer and that worked while Chrome was blocking the SVG sprite used in the `<svg>`/`<use>` element

Comment: You are loading SVG in your popup.html or content script?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592101/why-wont-the-svg-load-in-chrome-extension
Here is a similar question that could help.

Comment: It's in a content script and I'm already using the runtime getURL method to generate the path to it. However, Chrome is blocking it from being loaded

Comment: Check the [Requesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr) for chrome. By adding hosts or host match patterns (or both) to the permissions section of the manifest file, the extension can request access to remote servers outside of its origin.

Answer (score 0):

No, Chrome never blocks SVG file loading if it is enlisted in `web_accessible_resources`.

Please check the following:

- svg file path/regex mentioned in `web_accessible_resources` is correct
- you are fetching svg url via `chrome.runtime.getURL`
- also, check the path inside `chrome.runtime.getURL` function

Problem is chrome always give same error message:

`(index):1 Denying load of chrome-extension://pdlmeiogifooojmjbihodmcehpmjghho/Takkun.svg. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.`

...for any kind of issues related to `web_accessible_resources`.

I had some time and doubt about it, so I tested it on a simple chrome extension:
https://github.com/sonalsavaratkar/chrome-extension-seed/tree/so-48393958

It loads a svg file to the `body` element of any webpage as `background-image`.

Comment: Semantics aside, the issue is that Chrome is blocking the specified web accessible resource from being loaded and it loads just fine in Firefox.

Comment: It is web accessible. It does use the runtime getURL method and I've checked the path. I've taken a screenshot of the console logged path and as I keep saying, the SVG file appears just fine in Firefox.

Comment: This is what Chrome is saying about it: Unsafe attempt to load URL chrome-extension://ainfdhapdnpfbjbnjojoediompjnmkom/svgs/fa-regular.svg#clock Which I'm comparing your manifest and ours, your example works. Not sure why Chrome is blocking our SVG files, though.

Comment: It seems Chrome is blocking the SVG sprite being used in the <svg>/<use> element, but when using a non-sprite SVG as the background the way you did it loads just fine.

Comment: i am not sure about svg sprite man.but this thread has discussion similar to what you are doing. hope it helps:
https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody/issues/21